# Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

I am trying to save a custom class into core data but it is giving me this error on `@NSManaged public var deck: [card]?` in the generated NSManagedSubClass. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
extension Deck {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Deck> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Deck>(entityName: "Deck")
    }

    @NSManaged public var deck: [card]?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 @NSManaged public var deck: [card]?
```

The `card` of this line of code is a custom class, you cannot use it as a datatype in your NSManagedObject.

The solution is making Card a subclass of NSObject:

```
class Card: NSObject {
```

Comment: thanks That worked but now I am getting a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when I save the context, any idea what that's about?

Comment: here is the code - let addedDeck = Deck(context: context)
            
            addedDeck.name = deckNameInput.text
            addedDeck.deck = cardArray
            
            ad.saveContext()

Comment: Does "ad" mean  "let addedDeck = Deck(context: context)" ?    Did you miswrite "addedDeck" into "ad"?     I think the problem is that object "ad" has no saveContext() method.

Comment: no sorry ad is my shortcut to save context to app delegate

Comment: let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: call the saveContext like below:
 
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        ad.saveContext()
    } else {
    }
 
 saveContext method:
 
 func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }

Comment: whenever I call ad.saveContext() it crashes, not sure why